# Will a lot of if or statements cause performance issues?

Tags: php, performance, if-statement

I have a menu, which is conditionally displayed depending on language.

It looks like this:

```
if (
$page == "page1.htm" ||
$page == "page2.htm" ||
$page == "page3.htm" ||
etc couple 100 of those
) {
//output menu
}
```

I have a few hunderd of those or statements in a single if.

Will this measurably impact performance?

I am not interested in maintainability, but only in performance. I am wondering if it would be worth optimizing.

Comment: "I have a few hunderd of those or statements in a single if" --- that's a real win

Comment: I realize its a mess. But should I be worried?

Comment: Yes..., yes it will. You'd probably want to think about what you want to do. I mean really... a couple of 100 OR's?

Comment: @user1721135: it depends on how much you got paid for that. If less than $5/hr - then don't care, they (customer) deserve it

Comment: Please add your exact code to the question. Probably, you should be less worried about performance (I sincerely doubt this is a bottleneck), and more concerned with how to maintain your code.

Comment: its actually 10$ lol. Well, its a quick fix until we get a cms. However if this will cause noticeable performance hit i need to fix it niw

Comment: You'll possibly need to have 100,000 items to find performance issues but I bet the code is already unmaintainable. If performance is your only concern, just run the code and evaluate how it behaves.

Comment: Performance is the only concern. There are much much worse issues regarding maintainability.

Comment: if statements are efficient, but almost certainly your approach is not. Although with a 100 or so you're not likely to see a performance difference. Might be better to outline what you're trying to achieve and see if there's a better approach.

Comment: `Performance is the only concern.` - then you're wasting your time looking at this.

Comment: Im trying to outout different menus for different language pages and subsections, however the files are in radom folders, and I can't really find a sane solution.

Comment: "Performance is the only concern" --- then take a profiler and find a real bottle neck (if any)

Comment: @AD7six thx, I think ill just ignore it for now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, perhaps I'd better post my comment as an answer. If you really don't want (or cannot) rethink your code at this point:

```
$pages = array_fill_keys(array("page1.htm", "page2,htm", "page3.htm"), true);
if (array_key_exists($page, $pages))
{
    //do whatever
}
```

Then again, if you're checking if the client is requesting an existing page or not, you could consider using:

```
if (file_exists($page))
{
    require_once($page);
}
```

Or something like that. Of course, check the `$page` variable for values like `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`, or all too many `../..` bits and bolts... Never trust the network :)

Comment: The `array_fill_keys()`/`array_key_exists()`  approach is actually considerably more expensive than the `$cond || $cond || ...` approach, especially if the server uses opcode caching. The `file_exists()` approach is a reasonable one, but you **must** sanitise any use input before applying it to the file system like this! `basename()` is usually a good start.

Comment: @DaveRandom: not that I don't believe you or anything, but could you explain why `array_key_exists` and `array_fill_keys` is more expensive? I realize that, if `$page === 'page1.htm'` in the OP's example, there's nothing that'll outperform that, thanks to short-circuit evaluation

Comment: `array_fill_keys()` will do a full iteration of the input array to produce the output array (in other words, it's O(n)). Then `array_key_exists()` do a hash lookup on the key to see if it exists, which may also hit a hash collision so may require further iteration internally. A similar but cheaper approach would be `in_array()`, because this only runs the first iteration step, in a short-circuit manner similar to the OP's original approach. When you factor in the internal processing overhead of a function call and memory overhead of an array, it's quite a bit more expensive.

Comment: Having said that, all of this is micro-optimisation of the highest order - it would only make a meaningful difference if the number of valid possible matches was in the tens or even hundreds of thousands. IMO, the best approach to this is the most readable one and/or a dynamic approach like `file_exists()` (or better, `$page = __DIR__ . '/' . pathinfo($page, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.htm'; if (is_file($page)) { /* ... */ }`).

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you find yourself using `||` a lot in an `if` statement, then your probably best of using `in_array()`:

```
$validPages = Array("page1.htm", "page2,htm", "page3.htm");
if(in_array($page, $validPages)){
    //Output menu
}
```

Comment: Depending on the number of values, setting them as keys might be better regarding performance.

Comment: Or better yet: `$pages = array_fill_keys(array('page1.htm', 'page2.htm'), true);` and `if (array_key_exists($page, $pages))`

Comment: This still requires hundreds of hard coded values.

Comment: @MrCode, yes it does, but since the OP doesn't mention any pattern, I don't feel safe just assuming there is one

Comment: @MrCode Without more information, we can't tell where the values are coming from

Comment: @MrCode: OP commented on `preg_match` answer, saying there isn't a universal pattern that applies

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It's a good suggestion, I've up-voted your answer.

Comment: I think database is best. Easy to edit, easy to understand. I don't think performance will not be such serious issue in case of database. Even open source like, wordpress, joomla etc save page data in database. It shows it's not a bad idea to save in database

Comment: @F4r-20 Be that as it may, this still won't necessarily out perform OP's current code, the only difference is this is more readable. OP said he is only interested in performance.

Answer (score 4):

I would use RegExp for that, you could also edit by your own needs:

```
if (preg_match("/^page[0-9]{1,3}\.htm$/", $page)){
  //Execute if this is a page.
}
```

In my opinion it is better to create some sort of **complicated pattern / several patterns** to check with because it:

- Probably will improve performance
- Will keep your code clean (which is the most important)

Comment: Assuming `pageX.html` isn't just an example and the values really follow a pattern, this is a good idea.

Comment: it was just an example, there are lots of different pages. some with pattern some not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by F4r-20, using the `in_array()` is a good idea. In addition, if you are sure that the pages are going to be named as `page1.htm`, `page2.htm`, etc., you can use a `for loop` construct to do the task; like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<$no_of_pages; $i++){
  $pages[$i] = 'page'.($i+1).'.htm';
}

if(in_array($page, $pages)){
  //your condition here
}
```

You can also store the pages in a column in a table to can perform an sql query if needed.

And about the `||` operator, it does not necessarily check all the conditions (say 100). Whenever any condition satisfies, it stops there and enters into the body of the if statement. So, the best case is **1 condition** and the worst case is **100 conditions**.

Comment: `new Array($no_of_pages);` is not PHP. Also, if this were a viable approach, pattern matching to extract the numeric from the string and checking that it is within range would be considerably more efficient for such a large number of possible inputs. `in_array()` has the same short-circuit evaluation behaviour as a string of conditions with an OR relationship. It may actually be *more* expensive than the simple `if (...)` approach because of the internal function call overhead.

Comment: sorry about that. Ya, I knew that in_array() has the same short-circuit evaluation. I mentioned it just because the OP seemed to be ignorant of that.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer this instead those lines of code:

```
$page="page10.htm"; //Example data
$match=array();
preg_match('/page(\d*)\.htm/', $page,$match);
$match=$match[1];
switch($x)
{
    case $x>1 && $x<40:
    echo "uder 50";
    break;
    case $x>40:
    echo "upper 50";
    break;
}
```

Comment: scroll down to jari's answer...

Comment: added an example to clarify and even better pattern to catch all number without range limit , isnt it?

Comment: Not really: `switch ($x) { case $x>1:` can only happen if `$x === true`, that and the OP commented on Jari's suggestion, saying that the snippet was just an example, and that the pages don't all follow the same pattern